# Spring-security-oauth OAuthProviderTokenServices custom implementation in OAuth 1.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, oauth

I'm using Spring-security-oauth to secure a RESTful application, and I'm triying to implement a custom OAuthProviderTokenServices class in order to store tokens in a database.
All I got from the docs is:

> When creating your OAuthProviderTokenServices implementation, you may
>   want to consider extending the RandomValueProviderTokenServices which
>   creates tokens via random value and handles everything except for the
>   persistence of the tokens. There is also an in-memory implementation
>   of the OAuthProviderTokenServices that may be suitable [...]

which is fine, so I created a new custom class:

```
package experiments;

import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import org.springframework.security.oauth.provider.token.OAuthProviderTokenImpl;
import org.springframework.security.oauth.provider.token.RandomValueProviderTokenServices;

/**
 * Implementation of TokenServices that stores tokens in a database.
 *
 * @author Seether
 */
public class DatabaseProviderTokenServices extends RandomValueProviderTokenServices {

  protected final ConcurrentHashMap<String, OAuthProviderTokenImpl> tokenStore = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, OAuthProviderTokenImpl>();

  protected OAuthProviderTokenImpl readToken(String token) {
    return tokenStore.get(token);
  }

  protected void storeToken(String tokenValue, OAuthProviderTokenImpl token) {
    tokenStore.put(tokenValue, token);
  }

  protected OAuthProviderTokenImpl removeToken(String tokenValue) {
    return tokenStore.remove(tokenValue);
  }

}
```

which for now, as you can see, is identical to the InMemoryProviderTokenServices class.

My application uses the AccessConfirmationController from sparkl example, which is this:

```
package experiments;

import java.util.TreeMap;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.security.oauth.provider.ConsumerDetails;
import org.springframework.security.oauth.provider.ConsumerDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth.provider.token.OAuthProviderToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth.provider.token.OAuthProviderTokenServices;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

/**
 * Controller for retrieving the model for and displaying the confirmation page for access to a protected resource.
 * 
 * @author Ryan Heaton
 */
@Controller
public class AccessConfirmationController {

    private OAuthProviderTokenServices tokenServices;
    private ConsumerDetailsService consumerDetailsService;

    @RequestMapping("/oauth/confirm_access")
    public ModelAndView getAccessConfirmation(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        String token = request.getParameter("oauth_token");
        if (token == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("A request token to authorize must be provided.");
        }

        OAuthProviderToken providerToken = tokenServices.getToken(token);
        ConsumerDetails consumer = consumerDetailsService
                .loadConsumerByConsumerKey(providerToken.getConsumerKey());

        String callback = request.getParameter("oauth_callback");
        TreeMap<String, Object> model = new TreeMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("oauth_token", token);
        if (callback != null) {
            model.put("oauth_callback", callback);
        }
        model.put("consumer", consumer);
        return new ModelAndView("access_confirmation", model);
    }

    public void setTokenServices(OAuthProviderTokenServices tokenServices) {
        this.tokenServices = tokenServices;
    }

    public void setConsumerDetailsService(ConsumerDetailsService consumerDetailsService) {
        this.consumerDetailsService = consumerDetailsService;
    }
}
```

Now the question is: how do I tell my application to use my tokenServices implementation rather than the default one (which right now I belive is InMemoryProviderTokenServices)?

I tried messing around with the controller, but the fews attempt all led me to java.lang.IllegalStateExceptions.

I also noticed that there is a line in the config XML:

```
<oauth:token-services id="tokenServices"/>
```

Which might be a critical piece of the puzzle, as the related help reads:

> Element for declaring and configuring an in-memory implementation of
>   the provider token service.

If I just remove it, I get:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'accessConfirmationController' defined in
>   ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot
>   resolve reference to bean 'tokenServices' while setting bean property
>   'tokenServices'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'tokenServices' is defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny as answers come out of nowhere sometimes, expecially after it's been some time since you've started looking for them and you've just posted here. Oh well.

According to a code snippet randomly found [here](http://pastebin.com/u9qP9GjB), it looks like all I needed to do was to comment out that line from the XML configuration file:

```
<!--   <oauth:token-services id="tokenServices"/> -->
```

and replace it with this one:

```
<beans:bean id="tokenServices" class="experiments.DatabaseProviderTokenServices" />
```

where the class is of course my implementation.
By doing this, the DatabaseProviderTokenServices class is used in place of the default InMemoryProviderTokenServices class.